# How to construct a Recordset object with multiple Recordsets inside it?

Tags: vb6

I am trying to construct a Recordset object with multiple Recordsets inside it.  I am trying to use the .NextRecordset method to do it, but I am having trouble.  Specifically I get `Current provider does not support returning multiple recordsets from a single execution.` error upon executing `.NextRecordset` method.

```
Dim oRs As ADODB.Recordset
Set oRs = New ADODB.Recordset
oRs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

oRs.Fields.Append "hello1", adVarChar, 100, adFldUpdatable
oRs.Fields.Append "hello2", adVarChar, 100, adFldUpdatable

oRs.Open , , adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
oRs.AddNew
oRs.Fields("hello1") = "234"
oRs.Fields("hello2") = "234"

Set oRs = oRs.NextRecordset       ' BLOWS UP
'  Add some columns + rows to this recordset
```

The additional complication is that I need to do this in C# (via Interop), but I'd be happy to first figure it out in VB6.

So, is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: "Recordset object with multiple Recordsets inside it." Er, I believe such construct just doesn't exist. Or I misunderstand your intentions. `oRS.NextRecordset` is not "give me a recordset from inside this one". Rather it is just "dear provider, please give me the next recordset". Perhaps it could help if you disclose more general goal.

Comment: @IlyaKurnosov You have it correct.  Essentially, I want to replicate the .NET DataSet (e.g. a set with multiple DataTable objects).

Comment: @AngryHacker - So in other words you want some sort of Super Recordset that contains multiple recordsets inside it?  What about an array of Recordsets?  Would that give you the same functionality you're looking for?

Comment: @Tim That would work, but the client of this library expects a "super" Recordset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest thing to what you seem to want is a *Hierarchical Recordset* in ADO.  These can go multiple levels deep, or just two levels (a Recordset contining Chapter fields) as in your request:

> Regardless of which way the parent Recordset is formed, it will contain a chapter column that is used to relate it to a child Recordset. If you wish, the parent Recordset may also have columns that contain aggregates (SUM, MIN, MAX, and so on) over the child rows. Both the parent and the child Recordset may have columns which contain an expression on the row in the Recordset, as well as columns which are new and initially empty.
>
> You can nest hierarchical Recordset objects to any depth (that is, create child Recordset objects of child Recordset objects, and so on).
>
> You can access the Recordset components of the shaped Recordset programmatically or through an appropriate visual control.

The key to this is using the Data Shaping Service, an OLEDB Provider which "rides on top of" your underlying Provider (even if only the local Cursor Service Provider *implied* when using client-side cursors).

Some description and a crude example can be found in the [How To Create Hierarchical Recordsets Programmatically](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196029) Support article.

More details and reference material can be found at [Data Shaping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676186%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), including the SQL-like language used to define Shape commands.

---

Or are you asking about *paged* Recordsets, as in [PageSize Property (ADO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting idea, but the caller app of this library is expecting a standard Recordset object that can be iterated via .NextRecordset method.

Comment: I suppose you are stuck then.  The ADO documentation says pretty clearly that "The NextRecordset method is not available on a disconnected Recordset object."